# Prolog: handling cycles in graph traversal

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, cycle, graph-traversal

```
road(london, paris, 135).
road(paris, london, 135).
road(paris, madrid, 250).
road(madrid, paris, 250).
road(madrid, barcelona, 70).
road(barcelona, madrid, 70).

route(X, Y, [X|Y], N) :-
   road(X, Y, N).
route(X, Y, [X|T], N) :- 
   road(X, Z, A),
   route(Z, Y, [_|T], B),
   N is A + B.
```

This is a sample code of the problem I am facing. My test input is

```
?- route(london, barcelona, R, 455).
```

This input will keep re-iterating through london-paris and paris-london, however I have noticed that it will find the route from london-barcelona if I remove, the cycle paris-london.

My question is if there is any way I can implement a predicate which will allow me to ignore a cycle.

Comment: Use `memberchk/2` and another argument to ensure that you are not considering a place you've already used.

Comment: this `route(X, Y, [X|Y], N) :- road(X, Y, N).` is surely wrong: Y is an atom, not a list

Answer (score 2):

You can do these modifications:

```
road(london, paris, 135).
road(paris, madrid, 250).
road(madrid, paris, 250). 
road(madrid, barcelona, 70).
road(barcelona, madrid, 70).

path(From, To, List, N) :-
   route(From, To, [From], N).

route(X, Y, Passed_city, N) :-
   road(X, Y, N).
route(X, Y, Passed_city, N) :- 
   road(X, Z, A),
   \+ member(Z, Passed_city),
   route(Z, Y, [Z|Passed_city], B),
   N is A + B.
```

and call the query

```
?- path(london, barcelona, R, 455).
```

What I did is to create a new rule for `path/4`
to insert the first city **From** in the list which contains all the cities you passed, like so: `route(From, To, [From], N)`.

Then I've inserted the goal `\+ member(Z, Passed_city)`
in the body of the second rule.

`\+` means "not provable", so
`\+ member(Z, Passed_city)` is true if `member(Z, Passed_city)` fails, that is, if `Z` is not in `Passed_city`.

Comment: s(X), but what about that 3rd argument of `path/4`, `List`? That variable is somewhat disconnected... intentional?

Comment: Yes, It's the list which contains all cities of the path. So in london-barcelona it contains [barcelona, madrid, paris, london]

Answer (score -2):

```
Now work..

road(london, paris, 135).
road(paris, madrid, 250).
road(madrid, paris, 250). 
road(madrid, barcelona, 70).
road(barcelona, madrid, 70).

path(From, To, List, N) :-
   route(From, To, [From], N).

route(X, Y, Passed_city, N) :-
   road(X, Y, N), Passed_city = [Passed_city|Y].
route(X, Y, Passed_city, N) :- 
   road(X, Z, A),
   \+ member(Z, Passed_city),
   route(Z, Y, [Z|Passed_city], B),
   N is A + B.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post an explanation or description about your code. An answer is supposed to have more than just code on stackoverflow , else it will be closed.